# Is nil coerced to null when calling Java from JRuby?

Tags: jruby

https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby indicates that the Java `null` object is coerced to Ruby's `nil`, but it doesn't mention if coercion occurs in the other direction (e.g. when an argument is passed to a Java method). Does it? If not, how can you create `null` from JRuby?

I did note that `nil.to_java` returns `nil`.

Comment: Please post the sample code you tried to see what happens. This is a **very** easy thing to test locally.

Comment: I don't understand your question. I already shared the result of trying `nil.to_java`. When I tried passing `nil` as an argument for a java method, I was told that no method matched the signature. Since posting this question, I got around that by using `java_send`, declaring the argument type and passing in `nil`, which I gather was (effectively) coerced to `null` in that case. If you tell me how else I can test coercion in JRuby irb, I will gladly try it.

Comment: "no method matched the signature" - this is a pretty different question; you should probably ask it separately. I doubt that the answer to the posed question (nil / null) will tell you more about your real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, the answer to your question is **yes**.

To see this for yourself, just try passing `nil` to any Java method and see what happens, it's pretty easy to do:

```
> java.lang.System.out.println(nil)
null
 => nil
```

Or

```
> java.lang.String.new(nil)
Java::JavaLang::NullPointerException:
```

Comment: What version of JRuby are you using?  When I execute `java.lang.System.out.println(nil)` on `jruby 1.7.10 (2.0.0p195) 2014-01-09 c4ecd6b on Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609 [darwin-i386]` in 2.0 mode
, I get `Java::JavaLang::NullPointerException: 
 from java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:110)`

Comment: I was using `jruby 1.7.10 (1.9.3p392) 2014-01-09 c4ecd6b on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_45-b18 [darwin-x86_64]` but I get the same results in the (half-supported) 2.0 mode. Must be a JVM difference. However, throwing a NullPointerException is a pretty good indication too.

Comment: Ok, based on the first example printing `null` in 1.9 mode, I'll accept that. The null pointer exceptions aren't convincing because Java doesn't produce that error and those could be implementation errors. Any comment on `nil.to_java` returning `nil`? That implies to me that there is no "coercion" going on at all and that Java's `null` is represented exactly _as_ Ruby's `nil`. In any event, I think the JRuby wiki needs updating.

Comment: Java certainly produces that error. See the [5 line reproduction](https://gist.github.com/shepmaster/9010704). Any time you print `null` from Ruby, it will need to be coerced back to `nil` to be printed. That's why the `println` call (which lives entirely in Java) is useful. Java's `null` and Ruby's `nil` are not the same thing. A large difference is that `nil` has methods that you can call on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  JavaUtil.primitive_to_java(nil)
```

Comment: That gave me `[2] pry(QRCoverSheet)> Java.primitive_to_java(nil)
ArgumentError: Java package `java' does not have a method `primitive_to_java'
from file:/Users/palfvin/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.10/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/java/java_module.rb:13:in `method_missing'
[3] pry(QRCoverSheet)>`

Comment: Wrong object name(already edited). Import this and use it, it should solve it http://jruby.org/apidocs/org/jruby/javasupport/JavaUtil.html

Comment: Assuming you're talking about http://jruby.org/apidocs/org/jruby/javasupport/JavaUtil.html, that method takes three arguments and it's also deprecated. Have you tried running it?